# How to get the value of a JSON key using Postman?

Tags: json, postman

I have an API that returns JSON. Using Postman, I want to send a `GET` request that returns the value of a key.

`GET http://localhost/user/1` will return:

```
{
    "firstName": "First",
    "lastName": "Last",
}
```

I've tried...

`GET http://localhost/user/1.firstName`
or
`GET http://localhost/user/1:firstName`:

```
{
    "error": "E_UNKNOWN",
    "status": 500,
    "summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
    "raw": {
        "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
        "errno": 1054,
        "sqlState": "42S22",
        "index": 0
    }
}
```

`GET http://localhost/user/1?firstName` will return:

```
{
    "firstName": "First",
    "lastName": "Last",
}
```

I want to send something like `GET http://localhost/user/1?firstName` that returns:

```
{
    "firstName": "First"
}
```

Is this possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi, maybe obsolete for you but have you tried something like GET http://localhost/user/1?filter=firstname  ?